# Elastic search sorts the words within string itself, not the overall results

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

When I do something like

```
    {
  "sort": [
    {
      "name": {"order": "desc"}
    }
  ]}
```

The resulting names are sorted within that name string itself, not by the results as a whole:

```
"name" : "Test asdf"
```

The sort value is

```
"sort": ["asdf"]
```

Is that expected? How can I get it sort the results as a whole by the name field and order them as specified (asc vs. desc)

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: in the mapping make name  a [multi field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html) with one version set to not analyzed which should be used for  sort.

Comment: and if I'm unable to modify the mapping, is there any way to workaround?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change the mapping to `not_analyzed` or use `keyword` analyzer, then use a script for sorting:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "script": "_source.name",
      "lang": "groovy",
      "type": "string",
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, this requires dynamic scripting to be enabled. If you don't have the possibility to enable it, or don't want to, place the script on file and use that in the query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "script_file": "source_sorting_script",
      "lang": "groovy",
      "type": "string",
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

where `source_sorting_script.groovy` contains just `_source.name` and should be placed under `/config/scripts` directory.